# How to fetch size details from storage account in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-monitoring

I am trying to fetch the size details or Used Capacity using Azure Monitoring API but it's returning me blank json.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

#start_time = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"
#end_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"

start_time = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=23)).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"
end_time = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=22)).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"



#print("Start_Time:",start_time)
#print("End_Time:",end_time)

subscription_id = ""
resource_group = ""
storage_account_name = ""
metric_name = "UsedCapacity" 
time_range = f"{start_time}/{end_time}"  
api_version = "2021-05-01"

tenant_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="scope",key="tenant-id")
client_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="scope", key="clientid")
client_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="sn_scope", key="secret")

token_endpoint = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token" 

data = {
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": f"{client_id}",  
  "client_secret": f"{client_secret}",  
  "resource": "https://management.azure.com/"
}

response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=data)

if response.status_code == 200:
  post_response = response.text
  print("POST_Response:",post_response)
  access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
  #print("Access Token:", access_token)
else:
  print("Error generating access token:", response.status_code)


headers = {
  "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
  "Content-Type" : "application/json"
}


api_url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storage_account_name}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan={time_range}&metricnames={metric_name}&api-version={api_version}"


print("API:",api_url)

response = requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
  data = response.text
  print("GET_Response:",data)
else:
  print("Error retrieving metrics data:", response.status_code)
  print("Error Message:",response.text)
```

Response I am getting from this API is 200 but the json file only returns { "value" :[] }
Is there any other API to fetch the size of storage account?

Comment: Please show us the actual `api_url` that is generated - you have a `print("API:",api_url)` line already. I suspect you might not be correctly percent-encoding your querystring parameters as you're using `f""`-strings quite liberally (and often unnecessarily) in your code there...

Comment: Using `"Content-Type" : "application/json"` on a `GET` request without a body is invalid. You should remove that header. (Did you meant to use `Accept` instead?)

Comment: @Dai Hi , I can't share the URL but the issue is not how the url is formed and even If I remove Content-Type from headers the output is same.

Comment: Your code-asis, will render `...?timespan=2023-06-14T09:31:06Z/2023-06-14T10:31:06Z&metricnames=...` such that the `/` is not percent-encoded - I'm pretty sure that it should be `%2F` as-in: `...?timespan=2023-06-14T09:31:06Z%2F2023-06-14T10:31:06Z&metricnames=...` - does it work if you make that change? and what happens if you make the same request using `cURL` or `wget` from the command-line instead of from within Python?

Comment: @Dai I have tried with %2F still the same output. Let me try it with cURL. Even with Postman I get empty json.

Comment: @Dai Hello , It worked on Azure CLI but I still don't get why in Python and Postman it's not working

Comment: Use a tool like Telerik Fiddler to examine the HTTP request being made by the `az` CLI and compare that to the one from `cURL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to fetch size details from storage account in Azure using Python.

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I created App to get the Client-id,tenant-id and Client-secret.

[image]

Assigned **`contributor`** role to the **`appvenkat`** under subscription level.

[image]

I tried with the same code with minimal modification and I can able to fetch the used capacity of the storage account using Python.

**Code:**

```
    import requests
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    
    start_time = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=23)).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"
    end_time = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=22)).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat() + "Z"
    
    
    subscription_id = "your subscription id"
    resource_group = "your resourcegroup name"
    storage_account_name = "your storage account name"
    metric_name = "UsedCapacity" 
    time_range = f"{start_time}/{end_time}"  
    api_version = "2021-05-01"
    
    tenant_id = "your tenant id"
    client_id = "your client id"
    client_secret = "your client secret
    
    token_endpoint = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token" 
    
    data = {
      "grant_type": "client_credentials",
      "client_id": f"{client_id}",  
      "client_secret": f"{client_secret}",  
      "resource": "https://management.azure.com/"
    }
    
    response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=data)
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
      post_response = response.text
      #print("POST_Response:",post_response)
      access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
    #   print("Access Token:", access_token)
    else:
      print("Error generating access token:", response.status_code)
    
    
    headers = {
      "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
    
    
    api_url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{storage_account_name}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan={time_range}&metricnames={metric_name}&api-version={api_version}"
    
    
    print("API:",api_url)
    
    response = requests.get(api_url,headers=headers)
    print(response)
    print (response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

**Output:**

```
API: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat123/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?timespan=2023-06-15T08:11:21Z/2023-06-15T09:11:21Z&metricnames=UsedCapacity&api-version=2021-05-01
<Response [200]>
{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Expires': '-1', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'x-ms-correlation-request-id': 'ad9c6052-xxx2', 'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads': '11974', 'Request-Context': 'appId=cid-v1:b0xxxx', 'x-ms-request-id': '{ad9c6xxxxx2}', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'xxxxZ:ad9c605xxxxx2', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Fri, 16 Jun 2023 07:11:22 GMT'}
Used capacity of Storage account:
{"cost":59,"timespan":"2023-06-15T08:11:21Z/2023-06-15T09:11:21Z","interval":"PT1H","value":[{"id":"/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkat123/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/UsedCapacity","type":"Microsoft.Insights/metrics","name":{"value":"UsedCapacity","localizedValue":"Used capacity"},"displayDescription":"The amount of storage used by the storage account. For standard storage accounts, it's the sum of capacity used by blob, table, file, and queue. For premium storage accounts and Blob storage accounts, it is the same as BlobCapacity or FileCapacity.","unit":"Bytes","timeseries":[{"metadatavalues":[],"data":[{"timeStamp":"2023-06-15T08:11:00Z","average":2160775175}]}],"errorCode":"Success"}],"namespace":"Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts","resourceregion":"eastus"}
```

[image]